# How can i ignore this tag directly for using only text information with using JSOUP?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am making a scraper which is scraping product price and i need to ignore like this site div class but it is changeable for all web sites so this is really problem for me. You can see here i scrape first element and it comes like this

```
1 - <div class="ProductPrice"> 
     <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category1_ctrl_0_ctrl_7_mainGrid_ctl00_PUnit_lblPriceWithTax">47,00 TL</span> 
    </div>
```

Then i scrape second one this scrape again  tag(tag names can be changeable so pls consider this before answer)

```
 2 - <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Category1_ctrl_0_ctrl_7_mainGrid_ctl00_PUnit_lblPriceWithTax">47,00 TL</span>
```

My code is :

```
Elements allElements = newDocument.getAllElements();
        for (int j = 0; j < allElements.size(); j++) {
            Element element = allElements.get(j);
            if (element.text().matches(regex){
             // Writing to console.
            }
         }
```

Comment: i wanna get only <span> .. tag's text item but div item coming too. So i need to ignore all tags except one tag which only has text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   while (loopBool)
    {
        if (element.children() != null)
        {
            if (element.children().size() >= k)
            {
                if (!element.child(k).text().matches(regex))
                {

                    k++;
                }
                else
                {
                    element.empty();
                    loopBool = false;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                k = 0;
                element = element.child(k);
            }
        }

    }
```

I solved this problem with controlling element has got a children ? then if it has children then check they match regex, if they not match just circulate childs to find acceptable element.

Answer (score 0):

I would try (untested code):

```
Elements elements = newDocument.select("div[class*=ProductPrice]");
for (Element element : elements) {
    Element inner = element.html();
    //do whatever you want with "inner", containing your span
}
```

Edit: After your comment, I think, you should use `Elements elements = newDocument.select("*:matches(regex)");`, with "regex" the regular expression you need to extract a price. This should give you the liste of elements you need, without using `element.html();`:

```
Elements elements = newDocument.select("*:matches("+regex+")");
for (Element element : elements) {
    //do whatever you want with "inner", containing your span
}
```

Comment: Did you read this "(tag names can be changeable so pls consider this before answer)" ? i need determine which tag class has text which is i am looking for.With this structure only few web sites may work.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know what you are looking for?

Comment: cause i only need prices like 47.00 € or 56,844,65 $ with their symbols. need to ignore like "<div>" tags so i only need elements which has only got text() items.

Comment: So you are looking for Elements with only one child node being a text node, containing a number ending with a currency symbol. Is that correct?

Comment: The syntax seems pretty clear to me. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: it didnt work :/ But i didnt know this it can change something about part of this code.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace? What's your regex?

Comment: ^\-?\$?\TL?([1-9][0-9]{0,2}[,.]?([0-9]{3}[,.])*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)([,.]?[0-9][0-9])?[ ]?(руб.)?(TRY)?(TL)?[$]?[€]?[¥]?[£]?$

Comment: is my regex for getting price.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12857/discussion-between-ercin-akcay-and-traroth)